# (deflate + base64 в C#)

Tags: c#, gzip, deflate

Здравствуйте. Предстоит задача зашифровать и расшифровать текст, который скорее всего закодирован в Deflate + base64. Пример запроса:

```
<iq from='masterserver@cocbuilder/pve' to='660748410@warface/GameClient' xml:lang='en' id='uid0000000e' type='result'><query xmlns='urn:netw:k01'><data query_name='items' code='2' from='2000' to='2250' hash='-1840816409' compressedData='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' originalSize='19296'/></query></iq>
```

Зашифрованный текст содержится в аттрибуте CompressedData

Нужно расшифровать и научится шифровать текст таким способом. Много бродил по интернету, но безрезультатно.
Данный сервис смог расшифровать http://txtwizard.net/compression

Кто может, помогите написать 2-е функции на расшифровку и шифровку этого текста на языке C#. Кто поможет, огромнейшее спасибо!

Comment: Это не шифрование, а сжатие и преобразование в base64 для передачи по сети.

Comment: Пример сжатия [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.7.php)

Comment: Если ваш текст прогнать преобразовать в байты base64 и попробовать распаковать через deflate - выдает ошибку Block length does not match with its complement. так что скорее всего там не deflate. (точнее, там deflate + два байта перед ним - zlib)

Comment: прогоните строчку через Convert.FromBase64Strin, полученные байты - через ZlibStream из dotnetzip. И обратно для сжатия.

Comment: Павел, огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. Тему можно закрыть. 
Вместо DeflateStream нужно использовать ZlibStream из DotNetZip

Спасибо большое [PashaPash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177221/pashapash) за решение.

Код:

```
internal class DeflateTool
{
    internal static string Decode(string base64encoded)
    {
        byte[] buff = Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded);
        using (ZlibStream StreamZlib = new ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(buff), Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            return new StreamReader(StreamZlib).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    internal static string Encode(string text)
    {
        byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        using (ZlibStream StreamZlib = new ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(buff), Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ReadStream(StreamZlib));
        }
    }
    internal static byte[] ReadStream(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```